# Is there a shortcut way to autofill a form using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm on a project where I will be adding a receipt that will be shown after the user has submitted a form. There is no efficient way to test the form as I would have to fill in the form everytime to confirm that the questions and answers makes their way into the receipt.

I want to create a temporary single method `autoFill()` that is tied to an anchor element in order to automatically fill in the form with answers. In Javascript I can do this with something like `document.getElementById('id').value = myValue`, but in Angular there seems to be no way to set an input element's value this way.
Instead, I would have to rewrite all the input fiels in the component by writing input setups.
All the examples I have seen includes rewriting the component itself, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-click-me',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
    {{clickMessage}}`
})
export class ClickMeComponent {
  clickMessage = '';

  onClickMe() {
    this.clickMessage = 'You are my hero!';
  }
}
```

But I don't want to change the original code.

I also don't want to install any dependencies like Selenium, although it would be a great choice.

Isn't there an easier way?

This is something like I would be looking for to be able to call in an Angular project:

```
autoFill() {
    document.getElementById('input1').value = "myTextValue";
    document.getElementById('input2').value = "Dropdown2";
  
    var radioElements = document.getElementsByName("input3");
  
    for (var i=0; i<radioElements.length; i++) {
      if (radioElements[i].getAttribute('value') == 'Radio3') {
        radioElements[i].checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know you want to avoid selenium, but you are literally trying to do the thing that tools like selenium were created to do. Before that you had to do code changes. In short, yes, you must make code modifications or use something like Selenium.

Comment: to my understanding, what you'd need to do is create a 2 way binding. You first declare some JS values that you set manually (they can be empty). Then you create a button which alters these values.

Comment: If your inputs are not binded through ngModel or a FormControl, that's a problem. Otherwise, it would be easy to inject values. It also means you have no form validation, so it appears your form is not well implemented. So it would be such a bad thing to make it right.

Comment: After filling the form is there an API call? also, is there any validations in the form?

Comment: `in Angular there seems to be no way to set an input element's value this way` What do you mean? It's super easy, on the contrary. Use something like `<input [value]="input1"/>` and in your component, `let input1="myTextValue"`, job done

Comment: How about using Reactive Form in Angular, with that it is possible to set whole form data as `form.patchValue({...})` [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 2):

if you're using reactive-forms to manage your angular forms you can, according to [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value), declare your formcontrol in your template :

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input formControlName="input1">
</form>
```

and in your typescript :

```js
this.myForm.input1.setValue('');
```

or

```
this.myForm.patchValue({input1: '', input2 : ''});
```

NB: before being able to patch/modify the value of your input, you need to declare it as seen in the documentation, my favorite way is the following :

```js
export class MyComponent {
   myForm: FormGroup

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
     this.myForm = this.fb.group({
       input1 : ['default value'],
    ...
     })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying this at the moment, however I get this error message:
`Property 'builder' does not exist on type 'FormBuilder'. `
Is it a pseudonym for something else?

Comment: it should be `this.fb.group` instead of fb.builder

Comment: yup indeed @Indraraj26 I corrected, it's this.fb.group and not this.fb.builder